# Launch a variable series of activities (in the form of mandatory permission requests), while retaining the main activity in the back stack

Tags: android

So I'm trying to launch a series of mandatory permissions requests upon first launch of an app. I should mention this is for a COSU device scenario. Additionally, I want the activity to resume where it left off whether the permissions were just granted for the first time or if they were already granted previously.

These are special permissions that must be manually enabled by the user, such as Draw Over Other Apps. And I'm currently checking and handling them in onResume().

In order to provide an appropriate rationale for them for the user, I've added an AlertDialog (with an AlertDialog.Builder) that displays before being sent to each activity. The AlertDialog.Builder is re-instantiated upon each onResume(), and only the permissions that are lacking are added to the array. Then, I am calling this to display the alert and then take the user to the permission setting like this.

*Edit:* added additional relevant code.

```
private Intent adminActivateIntent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
private Intent drawOverlayIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
private Intent usageStatsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
. . .
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
. . .
        // initialize objects
        TaskStackBuilder sBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        sBuilder.addParentStack(ExampleApp.this);
        List<AlertDialog.Builder> alertBuilderList = new ArrayList<>();
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
. . .
             // add Draw Overlay to lists
            drawOverlayIntent.setFlags(drawOverlayIntent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            alertBuilder.setMessage(drawOverlayMessage);
            alertBuilderList.add(alertBuilder);
            sBuilder.addNextIntent(drawOverlayIntent);
. . .
                if (!permission1 || !permission2 || !permission3) {
                    // show rationale alert, then display permission setting
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, id) -> {
                        startActivity(sBuilder.getIntents()[0]);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilderList.get(0).create();
                    alert.show();*/
                }
```

Yet, when `startActivity(sBuilder.getIntents()[0]);` activates, the screen appears to launch a new activity and then crashes simultaneously with this logcat:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: setView = DecorView@df8bda[ExampleActivity] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
E/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
D/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][720,1280] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e0d06fc[ExampleActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
                                              dispatchDetachedFromWindow
```

I've also tried just using `startActivity(intent)` which works for the first two permissions, but I get the same error for the last two.

I'm not sure if it matters, but here's the activity in the manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.ExampleActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have tried debugging the exact call, but it is not leading me to any answers. Does anyone have a clue to what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out the problem on my own, and it wasn't even listed in my original code, so I'll update the example, and share what ended up working here.

I had been initializing my Intent objects before onCreate, and I found out that `getPackageName()` is from the ContextWrapper class. Thus, when it reached the point to call that intent, it was trying to reference an invalid context that had been attempted to be instantiated before one existed.